# Python direct exceptions in def to stdout

Tags: python

I have several defs designed like this :

```
def first():
    try:
       "Talking Business Here"
    except IOError, e:
       print e
    else:
       "Make a deal"

def second():
    try:
       "Business solution"
    except IOError, e:
       print e
       first()
    else:
        third()

def third():
    #Similar functionality


def main():
    second()

if __name__ == 'main':main()
```

I would like to collect all the `except` messages and `print` message into stdout. Then inside this python script, I would like to check the stdout and see if there is any message at all, something like :

```
if len(sys.stdout) > 0 :
    #Send me an email
```

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: So your real problem is checking to see whether any messages were logged?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use the [`logging` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) for this?

Comment: There's also an SMTPHandler you can use to send emails with logging messages

Comment: @TimPietzcker: some examples would be nice

Comment: @TimPietzcker : Never mind... Python doc...

Comment: I'd suggest running your Python script as a subprocess with stdout going into a pipe.  Then the parent process can read from that pipe, and if it reads any data before the process terminates, it can send the email.

Answer (score 2):

did you try this..

```
exeptions = []
def first():
    try:
       "Talking Business Here"
    except IOError, e:
       sys.stdout.write(e)
       exceptions.append(e)
    else:
       "Make a deal"
```

also you can try to append all the exceptions in a list and then

```
if len(exceptions) >0:
    "send me a mail"
```

Comment: `sys.stdout.write(e)` doesnt work for me. It complains this: `TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not exceptions.IOError`

Comment: are you doing this... `try: .... except Exception, e: sys.stdout.write(e)` because in this your e would be your exception type not the error message..

Comment: I am doing as written above. `except IOError, e: sys.stdout.write(e)`

Answer (score 2):

You can just assign the file descriptors, I think:

```
import sys

oldStderr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = sys.stdout
```

Now everything that goes to normally to `stderr` does now go to `stdout`.

With `oldStderr` you can "undo" the assignment when you don't want t anymore.

You can also collect everything in a [String-Stream](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) this way, if you create one before assigning it to `stderr`.

Comment: this is, imo, the best solution because it's simple and it works and for all exceptions without any extra code needed. You have to be careful though, as it works for all exceptions without any extra code needed